# Return MouseWheel value as scrolling/not scrolling in Processing every 3 seconds?

Tags: java, processing

I'm very new to Processing and am trying to make a simple program that handles a list of audio clips. When the user scrolls down using the mouse wheel, audio clips are skipped, and when they stop scrolling, an audio clip plays through.

The first step for this seems to be finding a way of converting the numbers returned from MouseWheel, which grow vastly larger or smaller as the mouse wheel is scrolled, into true/false-style values that are returned less frequently (every few seconds).

The code below returns true/false, but does so very quickly. If anybody could help me with saying, "scan for changes every 3 seconds", or similar, I'd be enormously appreciative.

```
int wheelVal; //reading from mouse wheel
boolean hasScrolled = false; // whether mouse has scrolled

void setup() {
size (750, 500); 
println ("ready to scroll");} 

void draw() {
background (450);}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent me)
{ wheelVal = me.getCount();
if (wheelVal > 0) { 
  hasScrolled = true;
  println ("true");}


if (wheelVal < 0) {
   hasScrolled = false;
   println ("false");}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, but you can probably actually simplify your logic a bit.

**Step 1:** Create a `hasScrolled` variable. Set it to `true` in the `mouseWheel()` function.

**Step 2:** Inside the `draw()` function, use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable to check when 3 seconds has gone by. If so, check the `hasScrolled` variable, and set it back to `false`.

Here's a small example:

```
boolean hasScrolled = false;

void draw(){
   background(32);

   //180 frames is 3 seconds
   if(frameCount % 180 == 0){
     if(hasScrolled){
      println("scrolled!"); 
     }
   }
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent me){
 hasScrolled = true; 
}
```